# Making a substring plus data from sql database column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create, lets say a user ID. I have a sql server database and i have a user webpage developed in asp.net. On my user page, a user fill out the information in the text boxes(First Name, Last Name, Middle Initial and so on) and when a user clicks a submit button, the entered information is added to a database. I have an auto increment column in the database, so when the information is added to the database the row has a auto increment number, for example 1. Each time the new row is added the auto increment number rises on one.

I want to create an unique UserID. It should contain the first 4 letters of a Last Name, which user fills out on a user web page and the auto increment number from the database. I have a code to retrieve the first 4 letters of the last name ( string FirstFour = txtNewUserLN.Text.Substring(0, 4);) but i need to add auto increment number from the database  to that string.
Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: The auto incremented ID column should already be your UserID. Why would you use another one? Anyway: Please show us your code, without it's hard to help.

Comment: This is work for a TRIGGER on your table.Check the documentation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Yes, but the auto increment column is just a number, and i want to create that number with the first four letter of the last name to have a kind of user name.

Comment: Then follow Steve's tip. The alternative would be getting the ID after the SQL `insert` and doing an additional `update` which is not as clean as using `trigger`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an sql user defined function in sql database

for create an function
use

```
CREATE FUNCTION ucernamehandle(@Lastname)
RETURNS nchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idfromauo int;
    DECLARE @newusernem nchar(50);
    SET @idfromauo =IDENT_CURRENT('yourtablename');
    return @Lastname+@idfromauo;
END
```

and then use it in inset statement like

```
INSERT INTO yourtablename (LastName) VALUES (ucernamehandle(@Lastname))
```

then exactly you will get witch you want

welcome for your thank's

best of luck

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are going to have to do an insert and then an update. Something to watch out for - if you use anything that checks for the last or just inserted identity value, make sure you put it in a transaction. If you don't you could have other processes adding a record before you update.

So try something like this:

```
insert into UserList(LastName, FirstName, ...) values (@LastName, @FirstName)
declare @UserID varchar(500)
set @UserID = left(@LastName, 4) + convert(varchar(10), SCOPE_IDENTITY())
update UserList set UserID = @UserID where RowID = Scope_identity()
```